# Force geth to periodically save state to disk

Tags: go-ethereum, memory, lighthouse

I'm running a geth node with lighthouse, and I'm having an issue where geth will periodically crash due to being out of memory.  My system has 16 GB of RAM, and I'm not sure what the underlying issue is, but from tracking memory usage it actually seems like lighthouse is occasionally spiking in its usage just before the crash.

Until I can solve this problem, as a workaround, I have a script which detects when the node crashes and automatically restarts it.  However, one issue is that if the node has been running for a while, when it crashes it seems to resest to the state when it was last started, which sometimes means it will take a long time to resync.  Again, to try to workaround this I can periodically stop and restart that node so it is never too long since the last clean shutdown, but I was wondering if it is possible to just periodically force geth to save its state to disk, in the same way it does when shut down cleanly.